# google pie chart slices pass value through variable for offset

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

I am using google chart api and angularjs.I need to set slices value through variable.All example i have seen they are hardcoded or using foreach loop.How could i set  selected pie slice value through variable.Here is my code?"selectedRow" variable is passing as a string not as a variable.

```
        $scope.onSelectRowFunction = function(selectedItem)
        { 

           var selectedRow = parseInt(selectedItem.row);
           $scope.chartpie.options = {
                "slices": {selectedRow : {"offset": 0.4}},
                "title": "Title is here",
                "isStacked": "true",                    
                "sliceVisibilityThreshold": 0,
                "displayExactValues": true
           };


       };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
       $scope.chartpie.options = {
            "slices": {},
            "title": "Title is here",
            "isStacked": "true",                    
            "sliceVisibilityThreshold": 0,
            "displayExactValues": true
       };
       $scope.chartpie.options.slices[selectedRow] = {"offset": 0.4}
```